# Why did my LED burn up?

Tags: arduino, led, breadboard, troubleshooting

My circuit was basically a push button hooked at 5 volts with a 100 ohm resistor. The push-button was directly below the LED. Why did it burn? Why didn't the resistor work properly? As you can tell by my circuit, I'm just starting out with Arduino, so please give me simple answers so I can understand them!

Comment: Please show a schematic of your circuit (hit control-M while editing your question to start the schematic editor) and/or show a picture of your circuit.

Comment: How does an Arduino come into this? It's not in the circuit you described.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see. For an utterly unspecified LED, 20 or 30 mA is a likely maximum current.

V=IR so V/R=I

For unsophisticated (and safer, since it aims low) analysis, I pretend the LED has no voltage drop, so 5V/100 Ohms = 0.050 A = 50 mA - likely a problem, for an utterly unspecified LED.

Does sophistication save us? Empirically, no, since you burned your LED. But let's go there anyway. Say the LED drops 2V at operating current. So then you have 5V - 2V = 3V, and current is 3v/100 ohm = 0.030 A = 30 mA - likely a problem, for an utterly unspecified LED if it's of the more common 20 mA flavor. Or perhaps the LED actually operates at 1.85V, and the resulting 31.5 mA will happily kill a 30mA LED or a 20 mA  LED.

Try 250 ohms for a conservatively sized (*it could be brighter, but it should not burn up, and it should certainly be bright enough to see*) resistor for an utterly unspecified LED, on 5V...

Comment: Where can I check my LED's maximum current? All I know is that it's yellow...

Comment: @MatheusDutra you read the datasheet for the LED. Otherwise, you destructively test a bunch of them and experimentally figure out what is a suitable max current.

Comment: If you purchased it from a reputable supplier, it will have a known manufacturer and part number, and you can look at a datasheet for the part. i.e. MY yellow LEDs are Multicomp 87K7121 - Unknown random part, assume 20 mA, subject to revision if they expire at 20 mA. If you don't need it 'as bright as it can possibly be", try 1000 ohms, it might be plenty bright and should be very safe.

Comment: You might also want to take your meter an check the actual resistance of your 100 ohm resistor. If it's a 10 ohm, well, you've got your answer.

Comment: You were right, it says that the maximum is 24 mA. I thought all of my resistors worked. Thanks for the advice.